# Surface integral of a vector field and parameterized surface

Tags: surface-integrals

I have a question regarding this topic:

$\vec A = \frac {3 \vec r}{r^2}$ is our vector field. We need to find the flux for the enclosed volume of a sphere with radius R, that has a parametrized surface $\partial V=(R \cos\phi \sin \theta,R \sin\phi \sin \theta,R \cos \theta)$.

$\vec A = 3(\frac{x}{r^2},\frac{y}{r^2},\frac{z}{r^2})$

Now the general parametrisation of $\vec r$ is $\vec r=(\rho \cos\phi \sin \theta,\rho \sin\phi \sin \theta,\rho \cos \theta))$.

Then : $\vec A=3(\frac{\rho \cos\phi \sin \theta}{\rho^2},\frac{\rho \sin\phi \sin \theta}{\rho^2},\frac{\rho \cos\theta}{\rho^2})$.

If in this expression:

$$\int_{\partial V}\vec A(\vec r) d \vec f=\int_{\partial V}\vec A(\rho,\phi,\theta)$$

where $d\vec f$ is an infinitesimal surface element, we plug in the corresponding values, the result is not the same with the result when we write $\vec A$ as:

$\vec A=3(\frac{ \cos\phi \sin \theta}{R},\frac{\sin\phi \sin \theta}{R},\frac{ \cos\theta}{R})$ which gives you a result of $12\pi R$.

But my question is, why do we write $\vec A=3(\frac{ \cos\phi \sin \theta}{R},\frac{\sin\phi \sin \theta}{R},\frac{ \cos\theta}{R})$  when clearly $\vec r$ can take arbitrary values so that $|\vec r|< R$ or $|\vec r|> R$ or $|\vec r|=R$

Comment: Your integrand is calculated on the surface of the sphere, $\partial V$, which has constant $r=R$.  This seems to be a typical exercise of Gauss' Law.

Comment: Left hand side is direct surface integral and that is why $\rho = R$. Right hand side is applying divergence theorem which is a volume integral and that is why $0 \leq \rho \leq R$. I am not sure why you get different results. That shouldn't be the case for the vector field $ \displaystyle \frac{\hat \rho}{\rho}$